# Jquery - Event Listener on child div to change css property of parent div

Tags: jquery, css, forms, radio-button, onfocus

I am building a product customization form and the radio buttons are hidden with opacity:0.

I want the border of the image to become black as a feedback to the user that the option is selected. I have added event listener to the radio button so that on focus, it changes the css properties of parent div as a feedback to the user.
It works perfectly in chrome and jsfiddle, but not on mobile or safari browser.

Why is this happening and what is the workaround.

Here's the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gLwjhqtd/

```
 $('.radioButtons')
    .focus(function() {
      $(this).parent().css('border','2px solid black');
    })
    .blur(function() {
      $(this).parent().css('border','none');
    })
```

Thanks!

Comment: It might have something to do with the `focus` and `blur` events. I'm not sure they work as you expect on mobile browsers (in the context of `radio` buttons). You could set a listener on `change` and show the border if the radio is set, or remove it if not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

don't use blur or focus because in mobile they don't happen.
 you can try this

```
$('.radioButtons').change(function(event){
    $('.radioButtons').parent().css('border','0');
    if($(event.target).is(':checked'))
  {
    $(event.target).parent().css('border','2px solid black');
  }

})
```